# Google LockService doesn't seem to work at all

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking, critical-section

I'm trying to use the [LockService class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service).
But it doesn't seem to work at all!!

I have a button in a sheet (a drawing, in fact) that calls a method.

And at the beginnng of that method I have:

```
var Lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
var TryLock = Lock.tryLock(5000);
Browser.msgBox(TryLock.toString());
if (!TryLock)
{
  return;
}

Browser.msgBox("Haslock " + Lock.hasLock().toString());

//script's body, nothing related to Locks
//everything related to the current (and only) document

Lock.releaseLock();
```

So, in first place, `TryLock` is ALWAYS `true`! No matter how many times I press the button to run two, three or ten scripts at once. (The script is long enough to take about one minute).

And second, `hasLock` is ALWAYS `false`! That is completely against the documentation.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Here is (I think) what's happening: the first execution acquires the lock. No subsequent executions can pass the tryLock call because your code never releases the lock, and they give up after 5 seconds. The only bit that doesn't make sense from your code, is the hasLock value - have you shown all your code?

Comment: No, I haven't shown the entire code. I have a "releaseLock" at the end, but perhaps the first attempts with a bug in the middle may have held the lock. But! In that case, `tryLock` should never return `true`.

Comment: By the way, all the alerts are shown before the five seconds.

Comment: actually tryLock will return TRUE for the first call, and any other calls which succeed in acquiring the lock after a previous one has released it :) the tricky bit here is factoring the asynchronous nature of the routine, and it's hard to appreciate all the implications without seeing the entire code.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, but truth is it always returns true. It's purpose is exactly to handle concurrent scripts (and assynchronous scripts fall into that case). Updated the code, but that really doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes I use Locks quite a bit myself too, and the only time it didn't make sense was when calls were executed at different times, and had different durations. Also, calls are not always executed immediately, and may in fact execute in a different order than called. What saved my sanity, was using the CacheService to manage chronological operations. You might consider doing something similar for your tests so that there is no delay with showing/clicking the dialog. You should cache each button call, cache the results of the callback separately, and then compare the results unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.... the big problem is that my script reads and writes, so I should rearrange it entirely in order to do that. But I found another way to "lock" things. I'm calling the script from a modal dialog now, the system never accepts two dialogs at once.

Comment: Seems you arrived at a bad time - CacheService & possibly LockService have been belly-up for 2 days. I was actually trying fire-fighting a number of app when you posted this, not knowing that was the cause. glad you found a solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason is the UI-object (Browser.msgBox()) drops the lock. Avoid or move the UI objects to reach concurrency.

```
var Lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
var TryLock = Lock.tryLock(10000);

Logger.log(Lock.hasLock()); // true
Logger.log(Lock.hasLock()); // true
  
Browser.msgBox(Lock.hasLock()); // true
Browser.msgBox(Lock.hasLock()); // false
```